# Loop through timer in c#

Tags: asp.net

I want execute a piece of code within a time period and want to exit after a certin time period.

I have a piece of code below which goes into infinite loop.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;


    }

   private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Page loaded", null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Default");
        }
   }
```

I want to run this code for 1 minute.
So how to stop the execution and get out of the loop after 50 or 60 seconds.

Plz help me in this.

Comment: How urgent?..............

Comment: @MitchWheat Client is waiting on the Company Floor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60);
}

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a boolean `m_SetEnabled = true` in your existing `OnElapsedTime event` and then add `if(m_SetEnabled) { m_SetEnabled = false; return; }` to just ignore the single event that gets fired.

Use the `Timer` class.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
public static void Main()
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval=5000;
    aTimer.Enabled=true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
    while(Console.Read()!='q');
}

 // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
 private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
 }
```

The `Elapsed` event will be raised every X amount of seconds, specified by the `Interval` property on the Timer object. It will call the `Event Handler` method you specify, in the example above it is `OnTimedEvent`